# Visual Studio and searching Wordpress Project

Tags: wordpress, visual-studio-code, woocommerce

I'm using Visual Studio as my IDE on a Wordpress project.
This is the first time I've developed a wordpress project so it is a bit of a learning curve and I'm wondering why I'm having difficulty navigating my way around the project.

For example: in the code I see something like `echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item );`

So I do a search for what is being printed.   by selecting the root of the project and `CMD` `SHIFT` `F` and search for `woocommerce_cart_item_quantity`, but the only result that is returned is the filter  being applied.  Where is the filter added?

Yet I know the code is being executed. When I comment out the line  `echo apply_filters(woocommerce_cart_item_quantity` I can see in the UI that a piece of markup is not being printed any more.  But I am not able to grep and find the code that is being executed when the filters are applied.

Anyone have any tips on how to navigate and find code?  Is this a Visual Studio issue or something relating to how Wordpress plugins are written?

This is not a question about how filters work, it is a question about navigating the project and finding the code the is being executed.

[image: Visual Studio Code search screen]

Comment: woocommerce_cart_item_quantity is not a function, its the filter key. You can hook custom function to this filter key. Take a look to [Wordpress Doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  But in this code `echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity',` how do I find what it is printing?  Should there not be some corresponing `add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_tiem_quantity' ` that I can search for?

Comment: Not necessarily, apply_filters allow plugins or themes to modify a given value. Here the goal is to allow a third party to change the value of the `$product_quantity` variable. So if no filter is applied to `woocommerce_cart_item_quantity`, this code will simply return the value of `$product_quantity` without any modification.

Answer (score 2):

> Hooks are a way for one piece of code to interact/modify another piece of code at specific, pre-defined spots. They make up the foundation for how plugins and themes interact with WordPress Core, but they’re also used extensively by Core itself.

- @See https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/

In short, hooks in WordPress essentially allow you to change or add code without editing core files. They are used extensively throughout WordPress and WooCommerce and are very useful for developers.

You can have a look at the [Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and you can lookup the [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) for specific WordPress core hooks.

Same goes for WooCommerce with the [WooCommerce Code Reference](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html).